# loop over a dataframe and populate with values

Tags: pandas

I am trying to loop over a dataframe and fill a new column with values according to a rule:

```
#formula for trading strategy
df['new_column'] = ""

for index,row in df.iterrows():
        if row.reversal == 1:
            row.new_column = 1
            index += 126
            row.new_column = -1
        else:
            row.new_column = 0
```

This formula is meant to populate the new column in a way that, when reversal=1, a value of 1 is given, followed by 0s for the next 125 rows, and a -1 in the 126th row. Then it should start again looking at whether the 127th item of the reversal column is 1 (indicating a reversal) or 0, etc. Instead, if reversal !=1, a value of 0 is given.

The problem is that when I take a look at the new column formed, it is still an empty column. There must be an error in the way I input the values in it. I looked at other ways to construct if statements for dataframes (e.g., lambda), but they do not allow me to perform all the operations in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new_column could have values: 0, 1 or -1, 
i suggest you to initially load 0 your column, so no need to set 0:

```
df['new_column'] = 0
index = 0
while index < df.shape[0]:
    if df['reversal'][index] == 1:
        df.loc[index,'new_column'] = 1            #set 1 to same index
        df.loc[index + 126, 'new_column'] = -1    #set -1 to 126th row
        index = index + 127                       #inc index to next loop
    else:
        index = index + 1
```

Be carefull the value of index is not bigger than the number of row of the dataframe

you could modify the test to secure the loop (to avoid error message):

```
    if df['reversal'][index] == 1 and (index + 126) < df.shape[0]:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frenchy. This was extremely useful, but one thing seems not to work (i.e., the index +=127 part). The code runs smoothly but when I analyse the result, I can see the next for loop does not start from the 127th row, in case the condition is satisfied. Instead, it goes through each row at a time. Please, let me know whether this is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much Frenchy. though, it still has the same issue. The index value does not update to index +127. it is like if 'index' is not modifiable

Comment: yes you have right,  the loop while is better in this case, i have replaced the for loop in sample

Comment: I think the issue may be solved (if so, you are the king)!!! I am checking the code now and get back to you. Thanks a lot